# How can I replace openssl.cfg in docker image

Tags: docker, .net-core, openssl

Since I am trying to access a 3:rd party http API which does not support TLS1.3 I need to replace the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cfg` with my custom version.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /

COPY ["WebApp/openssl.cnf","/etc/ssl/"]

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApp/WebApp.csproj", "WebApp/"]

RUN dotnet restore "WebApp/WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

Right now I can not figure out why putting the `COPY ["WebApp/openssl.cnf","/etc/ssl/"]` results in a "COPY failed, no such file or directory".

Where should it go or is there perhaps another way to enable TSL1/TLS1.1 in my container?

Answer (score 1):

The following Dockerfile worked for me:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /

COPY ["WebApp/openssl.cnf","/etc/ssl/"]

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

So I'm assuming it's a file structure issue. My file structure:

```
.
├── _Dockerfile
├── _WebApp
|   └── openssl.cnf
```

Alternatively, the issue could be with another part of the Dockerfile

Comment: i have the same issue and its not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113991/unable-to-update-openssl-cnf-file-using-dockerfile-command