# Unable to update Openssl.cnf file using Dockerfile command

Tags: dockerfile, .net-5

I am working on an application which is built on .NET 5 and we generate docker images. Lately I am having an issue with one of the custom docker images which I'm using as a base. I am getting SSL certificate error with few external endpoints in my application.

After doing some research on this issue, I found out that the `openssl.cnf` file should be updated with certain cipher strings and the TLS protocol needs to be set to 1.2.

I am able to achieve the results when I manually try to copy a new `openssl.cnf` file using command prompt commands

`docker cp openssl.cnf Alkaline_Pretty:etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

But when I try copy the new `openssl.cnf` file from the `Dockerfile` in my application, it doesn't update the file in the container location

My docker file looks something like this:

````
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM custom/docker/Imagefor/datadog:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Nuget.Config", "."]
COPY ["Directory.Build.props", "."]
COPY ["WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj", "WebApplication/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM base AS final
# Install ca-certificates
COPY WebApplication/SomeCertificate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/SomeCertificate.crt
COPY WebApplication/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN update-ca-certificates

#Datadog service name
ENV DD_SERVICE_NAME=myapplication
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
ENV DD_LOGS_INJECTION=true
ENV DD_TRACE_AGENT_PORT=8126

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"] ```


My file structure is something like this:

src 
   WebAppplication
    WebApplication.csproj
     openssl.cnf
````

Comment: In your `docker cp` you are using the path `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`. In your `dockerfile`, you are using `/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf`. Why that difference?

Comment: @omajid my bad, i was using /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf in the file too, sorry it was my mistake pushed the wrong one i have corrected it now

Comment: does this line of code  `COPY WebApplication/SomeCertificate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/SomeCertificate.crt` works? does the file gets there? If not sure, try a different new file, to rule it out. Also, have you tried copying any other file to the `/etc/ssl/` folder?

Comment: @nferreira78, so the issue is not with the certificate, issue is with openssl.cnf file which is not getting copied to the container path and not updated

Comment: thanks @abbs that's exactly what I needed to know, now are you trying to copy an updated `openssl.cnf` file? I mean a new version of the file, from the one that is in the previous image build?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Answer (score 0):

### Some of possible reasons for failure

1. `WebApplication/openssl.cnf` might be different from `openssl.cnf` used in example
2. Your application might destroy `openssl.cnf` on the container start - be sure, there is nothing toxic in source code, which might cause it
3. `update-ca-certificates` might have some side effects, which might with the new `openssl.cnf` break your app.

### Recommendation for debug

Try to `diff` the original `openssl.cnf` with the `openssl.cnf` in the container. It will help you to find the origin of the error.

If the `openssl.cnf` is intact, I would recommend to check, whether the new certificate bundle is the same as is in older images.

If the `openssl.cnf` is changed, try to find the source of the change. Changing the order of Dockerfile execution might help you with it.

Comment: thanks ill try to check this out